# how to add mysql driver jar file in eclipse

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc, jar

I have the jar file: `mysql-connector-java-5.1.14-bin.jar` and I want to add it to my project.
I add the jar at this way: project-> properties -> (Java Build Path) Libraries and add it from external jars. But when I try to use it and write:

`import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource;`

`import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource;`

I get error under "com.mysql".

What is my mistake?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: "The import com.mysql cannot be resolved"

Comment: Try to clean the project. Project... Clean

Comment: `import java.sql.*;` after adding external connector JAR, anyone?

Comment: Might be your connector jar is corrupt. You may try downloading it again or try to open it using an archive manager tool.

Answer (score 1):

If the JAR file for the JDBC driver appears in the "Referenced Libraries" branch of the project, like this:

[image: libraries.png]

then you don't need an `import` statement for it. Just use `DriverManager.getConnection()` and Java should be able to find the JDBC driver itself.

```java
String myConnectionString =
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307?" +
        "useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
// the following statement assumes
//     import java.sql.*;
Connection dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(myConnectionString, "root", "myPassword");
```

Comment: Thanks, that work. But the command:    MysqlDataSource ds = new MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource();
stil get error. how can I fix that?

Comment: @user1994587 In that case `import com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.*;` works fine for me.